# shorten sql union all

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

Is there a way to use the select and where statements once when using Union All?

Don't want to repeat it again and again

> SELECT PayrollNo
> FROM Table1
> where PayrollNo like 99
>
> UNION ALL
>
> SELECT PayrollNo
> FROM Table2
> where PayrollNo like 99
>
> UNION ALL
>
> SELECT PayrollNo
> FROM Table3
> where PayrollNo like 99

Comment: In MS Access, the answer is basically "no".  Plus, this version should have the best performance.

Comment: I don't have this product but I remember using global variable parameters so when you need to change 99 value for something else you do it just once.